# Xindy tutorials?

Tags: books, xindy

Aside from [the official documentation](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/tutorial.html#toc2) what other good Xindy tutorials are out there, either on the Internet or in textbooks (not necessarily in English)?

Comment: While not quite up your ally perhaps try `texdoc --view glossaries` from the command line. Specifically `texdoc --view glossaries-user`, Section 11 is entitled "Xindy {Option 3)". `glossaries-code` discusses the underlying TeX macros, which is probably not relevant. I suggest this since the Glossaries package optionally uses Xindy in the background. The information there does not qualify as a tutorial though.